# Include headers directories for gradle generation with JNI interaction

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to get C++ code to work with `react-native` (see [this](https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/react-native-jni) for the general steps).

I've generated my project with `react-native init`, generated the JNI bindings by using [Djinni](https://github.com/dropbox/djinni). I'm now trying to build the application and test it on my android emulator (`cd $PROJECT_ROOT/android && ./gradlew installDebug`). It seems like the header files aren't found, their directories aren't included :

```
> ./gradlew installDebug
(...)
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk
Warning: Deprecated NDK integration enabled by useDeprecatedNdk flag in gradle.properties will be removed from Android Gradle plugin soon.
Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration with the stable Android Gradle plugin:
 https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html
or use the experimental plugin:
 http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.

In file included from $PROJECT_ROOT/android/app/src/main/jni/NativeCppBridgeText.cpp:4:
$PROJECT_ROOT/android/app/src/main/jni/NativeCppBridgeText.hpp:6:10: fatal error: 'cpp_bridge_text.hpp' file not found
#include "cpp_bridge_text.hpp"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [$PROJECT_ROOT/android/app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/app/$PROJECT_ROOT/android/app/src/main/jni/NativeCppBridgeText.o] Error 1

:app:compileDebugNdk FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I managed to get past this small issue by creating hard links to the headers causing issues. Which leads me to this :

```
> ./gradlew installDebug
(...)
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk
Warning: Deprecated NDK integration enabled by useDeprecatedNdk flag in gradle.properties will be removed from Android Gradle plugin soon.
Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration with the stable Android Gradle plugin:
 https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html
or use the experimental plugin:
 http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.

In file included from $PROJECT_ROOT/android/app/src/main/jni/NativeCppBridgeText.cpp:4:
In file included from $PROJECT_ROOT/android/app/src/main/jni/NativeCppBridgeText.hpp:7:
$PROJECT_ROOT/app/src/main/jni/djinni_support.hpp:20:10: fatal error: 'exception' file not found
#include <exception>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [$PROJECT_ROOT/android/app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/app/$PROJECT_ROOT/android/app/src/main/jni/NativeCppBridgeText.o] Error 1

:app:compileDebugNdk FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

In this case, it seems like even standard libraries aren't included.

My question is : **how do I explicitly specify `gradle` to add directories to its search/indlude path?**

In regular Android projects, it seems that you can edit Android.mk/Application.mk files. There aren't such files in my folders ; I think that `gradle` actually generates an Android.mk file (in `$PROJECT_ROOT/android/app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/Android.mk`), I tried editing it (`LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` field) to add my directories, but it gets overwritten when I try another build.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit this in `$PROJECTROOT/android/app/build.gradle` :

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        (...)
        ndk {
            (...)
            cFlags = "-Ipath/to/directory/"
        }
    }
}
```

However, you will most likely encounter other issues (I know that for a fact, because I did). I'd recommend you to use the modern and user-friendly [CMake integration.](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#existing-project)

I'm gonna write down the general steps so that I can find it again sometime in the future :

- Add your files to the android project (under android studio or another IDE). There should be files in your `java/` folder, files in your `jni/` folder (JNI bridge files), and files in your `cpp/` folder (the native C++).
- Add a `CMakeLists.txt` file to your module (usually named `app` if you're using `react-native`).
- In this file, respect the following structure :

  ```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

  add_library( # Name of the library
               $(YOUR_LIBRARY_NAME)
               # Sets it as a shared library
               SHARED
               # Relative path to the source file(s)
               path/to/your/file.cpp path/to/other/file.cpp )

  # Allows you to add folders to the search path : similar to -Ipath/to/your/headerfolder/
  include_directories(path/to/your/headerfolder/)

  # Allows you to have special compilation flags for the specified library's compilation
  target_compile_options( $(YOUR_LIBRARY_NAME)
                          PRIVATE # You can also use PUBLIC/INTERFACE
                          -std=gnu++11 ) # Your option ; I needed this in my case
  ```
- Once it's done, you need to link gradle to your native library :

  - If you're using android studio, just use the information available in [this guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#existing-project) as it's very well explained.
  - If you aren't, I also advise you to check out [this guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#existing-project), because it's really well explained.

After that, you can either build the project in android studio, or `cd $(PROJECTROOT)/android && ./gradlew installDebug`. It should work.

Good luck!